# 2010 Honda Accord with intermittent electrical shut down problem

Tags: honda, electrical, audio, warning-light

I have a 2010 Honda Accord EXL with about 74,000 miles and I live in Southern California.

For the past 2 months, I've been experiencing intermittent electrical shut downs while driving:

Scenario 1: while driving, the audio will shut down briefly (<1 sec.) and turn itself back on

Scenario 2: while driving, the audio and engine will shut down briefly (<1 sec.) and turn themselves back on. Warning lights like the tire pressure light will flash red briefly; the triangle with exclamation mark in middle light will also flash; the RPM gauge will dip, the fuel gauge will dip quickly to empty before snapping back to the normal level.

The frequency of these events is random, last month I experienced them several times in a single day. After which, the car ran fine the next 3 weeks without any issues. This morning, I experienced both scenarios within an hour.

I know this is not a battery issue since these issues only occur while the car is running.

I'm still able to brake and the steering wheel still works.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? Moreover, is it safe to drive?

Thanks!

Comment: Intermittent problems like this are the bane of any mechanic and car owner.  I'd say it's pretty UNSAFE if the engine dies and does NOT come back, say, as you cross an intersection. To the problem - it might a be a loose connection or it might be an short circuit.  As a start, can you check the battery cables, and remove and re-insert all the fuses (so to "wipe" the contacts)?

Comment: since car will run without battery after starting its not a battery open problem. Then open to all fusepanels is unlikely ,so it must be an intermittent short circuit somewhere where the fuse doesn’t blow. all the symptoms point to this. which must be pretty close to the battery or alternator cable if not the battery itself with dendrites. A ampacity or capacity battery test will tell.

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 could I get an ampacity or capacity battery test at any auto shop or dealership?  What should I say to the mechanic so they understand clearly?

Comment: yes any garage can do an electrical power test for intermittent power loss and capacity . Midas does it free with other work done here.  I am working on the theory that a full load test will trigger the fault under same conditions (hot)

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 - I'm not seeing where the OP stated it runs without the battery ... but to that end, it is very poor practice to disconnect the battery while the engine is running (that's for others out there). This is a good way to fry your alternator.

Comment: @Paulster2. I think Tony was debunking the idea I brought up that the OP's intermittent electrical issue could be caused by a bad cable.  I see his point,  that is,  that the engine and radio would probably operate fine with a disconnected battery,  even though that's not a recommended condition.

Comment: Is the engine truly shutting down or is the car losing power in he interior? Anything aftermarket installed?

Answer (score 1):

I own Accord 2010 model & experienced same problem for the past two weeks. Culprit found to be Battery +ve terminal corrosion.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

To me, it sounds like an earthing issue. Check the engine compartment for any missing/loose/corroded earth wires.